# Looking for error in angular app that should produce Pop Up window but does not do so

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, popup

This code was written using angularJS and Bootstrap 3.1.1.

The HTML code of relevance:

```
<a href="" ng-hide="readonly" ng-click="chooseChemicalPopup(stepIndex,$index)">
{{constituent.chemical.name}}
<span ng-show="constituent.chemical.name">(edit)</span>
<span ng-hide="constituent.chemical.name>(click to choose) </span>
</a>
```

The JavaScript function that is called as a result of "ng-click":

```
  $scope.chooseChemicalPopup = function (stepIndex, constituentIndex) { 
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/views/templates/pick-chemical-popup.html',
        controller:  'ChooseChemicalPopupCtrl',
        size: '',
        resolve: 
        {
           chemicals: function () {
           return $scope.chemicals;
        },
        selected: function () 
        {
           return {
              chemical: $scope.record.steps[stepIndex].constituents[constituentIndex].chemical
                  };
        }
        }       
            });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
       $scope.record.steps[stepIndex].constituents[constituentIndex].chemical = selectedItem; 
 });  
});
```

The controller:

```
angular.module('cpdApp').controller(
         'ChooseChemicalPopupCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance,chemicals,selected) {

   $scope.chemicals = chemicals;
   $scope.selected = selected;

   $scope.ok - function() {
      $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.chemical);
   };
   $scope.cancel = function() {$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); };
});
```

I set a breakpoint in the JavaScript function. The function chooseChemicalPopup  does execute, but ChooseChemicalPopupCtrl does not and the pop up HTML never occurs. Does anyone see anything obvious? I inherited this code, so I can't really answer any "Whys". I will tell you that there are exactly two popups called in this code and neither appear. Both chooseChemicalPopup and ChooseChemicalPopUpCtrl are inside the same Javascript file. I posted this before without mentioning the controller that never seems to execute, and now I have modified the post to add this problem.
Thanks for your time. I am not really fluent in AngularJS or Bootstrap, so no problem is too obvious to point out.

Answer (score 0):

did you check that the modal has a `CSS z-index Property` ?

maybe the pop up it is showing but "back" of the main "view". so that, you can put a z-index property =999 or something like that.

example:

```
<div id="popup" style="z-index: 999;">
...
</div>
```

Comment: There are no z-index properties attached to any of the web pages. I did check, and the po-up is not coming up behind anything. It is not appearing.  The JavaScript function referencing the pop up is in directory /scripts/controllers. The Pop Up URL it references is in directory ../../views/templates in reference to the JavaScript function.  Does this mean that the URL directory reference should be different?

Answer (score 0):

Is the location of pick-chemical-popup.html correct in the templateUrl field? If yes, put a break point in ChooseChemicalPopupCtrl and see if the data to be displayed is being passed correctly.

Comment: There are no z-index properties attached to any of the web pages. I did check, and the po-up is not coming up behind anything. It is not appearing. The JavaScript function referencing the pop up is in directory /scripts/controllers. The Pop Up URL it references is in directory ../../views/templates in reference to the JavaScript function. Does this mean that the URL directory reference should be different? –

Comment: So far no answers that help. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you create a plnkr of your code and share with us?